# Working with SIP and VOIP

Tags: android, wifi, sip, voip

What is the best way to start off with `SIP` and `VOIP` other than `SIPdemo` and `SIPdroid` in android?

Please do suggest some good tutorial on this.

Comment: See if [this](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/13088-android-sip-voip-tutorial.html) helps. Just a note: I think you should use Google before posting questions here.

Answer (score 2):

PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia stack written in C and it supports audio, video, presence and instant messaging capabilities.It is designed to be very small in footprint, have high performance, and very flexible.

Please refer [link1](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) and [PDF](http://www.pjsip.org/release/0.5.4/PJSIP-Dev-Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) and [linphone](http://www.linphone.org/). If you wish to work with [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) you can go with this two open source project because this two are using [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) as well. I am working on same kind of project and I refer the SipDroid and SipDemo and till now everything worked fine for me.

Best Luck

Comment: if i want to use csipsimple in my own application then is it necessary to have knowledge of NDK??

Comment: @NiravBhandari if you want to do any modification which are done in NDK then yes,otherwise no. just build the project all libraries are compiled for you :)

Comment: thanks for answe.
thats fine. I dont want to do any modification. but what i need is I only want to implement some functionality from csip simple code. but stuck in its code. Is there any document for using its library..??
I would be pleased if you help me littel....i only want to have audio and instant messaging feature in my client.How can i achieve it using csip simple..i m stuck in code..need documentation for using its library

Comment: @NiravBhandari there are no specific document related to how to use those libraries,to understand and use those codes only way is dive into those codes. if you have any issues then definitely you can search as well post in its forum

Comment: thanks man...i would defiantly dive into this code to get proper understanding

Comment: @NiravBhandari All the best with that :)